# Parse and mongoDB json Object

Tags: java, android, json, parse-platform

I'm using the Parse API with mongoDB in my android application. In my database I have stored some values in a JSON Object like so :

```
"address": {
    "state": "blabla",
    "zipcode": 00000,
    "lane": "blabla",
    "city": "bla"
}
```

Saving works like a charm :

```
   try{
       JSONObject address = new JSONObject();
       address.put("lane",mLane);
       address.put("zipcode",mZipCode);
       address.put("city",mCity);
       address.put("state",mState);
       user.put("address", address);
       user.saveInBackground();
       Toast.makeText(getContext(),"SAvedSuccessfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     } catch (JSONException j){
         Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Error " +j,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
```

But I cannot figure out how to retrieve this data in my code. It always returns a null value. It works perfectly with other non JSON objects values.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj = ParseUser.getCurrentUser.getJSONObject("address");
```

Here obj is null...

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Why not have a Address Parse class?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

look at this example.

```
ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
gameScore.put("score", 1337);
gameScore.put("playerName", "Sean Plott");

gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);
gameScore.saveInBackground()`;
```

I would use Gson convert to a string then store in parse.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(address);
user.put("address",json);
```

now get the data.

```
Type type = new TypeToken<JSONObject>(){}.getType();
String json = ParseUser.getCurrentUser.getJSONObject("address");
JSONObject data = gson.fromJson(type,json);
```

Comment: Why not have a Address Parse class?

Answer (score -1):

You can even: first change `Parse` to `SharedPreferences`

create Share

```
public void putUser (String key, String value ) {
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("YourPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

next create JSONObject

```
JSONObject address = new JSONObject();
address.put("lane", "l");
address.put("zipcode", "z");
address.put("city", "c");
address.put("state", "s");
putUser("address", address.toString());
```

end get JSONObject

```
public String getUser (String key) {
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("YourPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
    return pref.getString(key, "");
}

JSONObject addressObject = new JSONObject(new String(getUser("address")));
if(addressObject != null) {
    addressObject.getString("lane");
    addressObject.getString("zipcode");
    addressObject.getString("city");
    addressObject.getString("state");
}
```

Comment: When I do that it returns an error and I can't save the data anymore  : JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject.

Comment: change user JSONArray put: user.put(address);

Comment: Can you explain a bit more ? The problem is when I try to retrieve the JSON object.

Comment: Suitable for you?

Answer (score -1):

Okey I figured it out thanks to @Caspain ! To save the data to the DB use :

```
    ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    JSONObject address = new JSONObject();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    try{
        address.put("lane",mLane);
        address.put("zipcode",mZipCode);
        address.put("city",mCity);
        address.put("state",mState);
    } catch (JSONException j){
        Log.i("TEST",j.toString());
    }
    String json = gson.toJson(address);
    user.put("address", json);
    user.saveInBackground();
```

And to retrieve the data :

```
String json = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getJSONObject("address").toString();
    try{
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject(json);
        String lane = data.getString("lane"); // do whatever with your JSON Object
    }catch (JSONException j){
        Log.i("Erreur",j.toString());
    }
```